# Using Django auth UserAdmin for a custom user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-authentication, django-custom-user

From the [Django.Contrib.Auth docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user):

> **Extending Django’s default User**
>   If you’re entirely happy with Django’s User model and you just want to add some additional profile information, you can simply subclass `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` and add your custom profile fields. This class provides the full implementation of the default User as an abstract model.

Said and done. I created a new model like below:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
  some_extra_data = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

This shows up in admin almost like Django's standard `User`. However, the most important difference in admin is that the password-(re)set field is not present, but a normal CharField is displayed instead. Do I really have to override stuff in the admin-config to get this to work? If so, how can I do that in somewhat DRY way (i.e. without copying stuff from the Django source... eww...)?

Answer (score 153):

After digging around the Django source code for a while, I found a working soultion. I am not totally happy with this solution, but it seems to work. Feel free to suggest better solutions!

---

Django uses `UserAdmin` to render the nice admin look for `User` model. By just using this in our `admin.py`-file, we can get the same look for our model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)
```

However, this alone is probably not a good solution, since Django Admin will not display any of your special fields. There are two reasons for this:

- `UserAdmin` uses `UserChangeForm` as the form to be used when modifying the object, which in its turn uses `User` as its model.
- `UserAdmin` defines a `formsets`-property, later used by `UserChangeForm`, which does not include your special fields.

So, I created a special change-form which overloads the Meta inner-class so that the change form uses the correct model. I also had to overload `UserAdmin` to add my special fields to the fieldset, which is the part of this solution I dislike a bit, since it looks a bit ugly. Feel free to suggest improvements!

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = MyUser

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm

    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
            (None, {'fields': ('some_extra_data',)}),
    )


admin.site.register(MyUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I was looking for, I'm doing the same with my custom user model, using the AbstractUser. This solution works great, some customization (hiding fields, adding your 'some_extra_data' in the 'Personal info') would be nice too but for now you made my day. Thanks @nico

Comment: Overloading of de UserAdmin fieldsets ugly? It works. Thanks.

Comment: Also note you need to override the user creation form, per the answer by @kdh454.

Comment: This is perfect, it's not messy at all. The django documentation points to this article: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model ... but I wasnt able to make it work with that, it was complaining about some User foreign key constraints. Might be related only to my project, nevertheless your solution works!

Answer (score 63):

A simpler solution, **admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from main.models import MyUser

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = MyUser

    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
            (None, {'fields': ('some_extra_data',)}),
    )

admin.site.register(MyUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

Django will correctly reference MyUser model for creation and modification.
I'm using Django 1.6.2.

Comment: I don't know why but I kept getting a "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'" when trying this.

Comment: I suggest you to inspect UserAdmin.fieldsets and see if it's None

Comment: Instead let `None`, you can input a string and it will be used as the title of the section in the admin form

Comment: Agree with @brillout, found this is the best answer. To add, you might get this error, which makes sense (Python 3.8, Django 3):
`ERRORS: <class 'users.admin.CustomerUserAdmin'>: (admin.E005) Both 'fieldsets' and 'fields' are specified.`

Answer (score 58):

nico's answer has been extremely helpful but I found Django still references the User model when creating a new user.

Ticket [#19353](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19353) references this problem.

In order to fix it i had to make a few more additions to `admin.py`

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm
from main.models import MyUser
from django import forms


class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = MyUser


class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = MyUser

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            MyUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        (None, {'fields': ('extra_field1', 'extra_field2',)}),
    )

admin.site.register(MyUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Note that starting in 1.6, the call to `forms.ValidationError` has a second argument: `code='duplicate_username'`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L101-L104 Also, I tried this on 1.6.5 and, for some reason, I didn't need to override `UserChangeForm` at all and the change form worked fine with my custom field. I can't explain why. It seems like it shouldn't have worked because of the `UserChangeForm` class having `model = User` present: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.5/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L138

Comment: FYI ticket [#19353](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19353) has now been fixed which essentially means that your solution may be redundant. If we just use @nip3o's solution we should be good.

Answer (score 13):

cesc's answer wasn't working for me when I attempted to add a custom field to the creation form. Perhaps it's changed since 1.6.2? Either way, I found adding the field to both fieldsets and add_fieldsets did the trick.

```
ADDITIONAL_USER_FIELDS = (
    (None, {'fields': ('some_additional_field',)}),
)

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = MyUser

    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + ADDITIONAL_USER_FIELDS
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + ADDITIONAL_USER_FIELDS

admin.site.register(MyUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to hook into the default sections instead of copying and pasting Django core code, you can extend the `UserAdmin` class and inject your fields into the `fieldsets` attribute as wished.

In Django v4.0.x, the `fieldsets` tuple you are modifying looks like this:

```py
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {"fields": ("username", "password")}),
        (_("Personal info"), {"fields": ("first_name", "last_name", "email")}),
        (
            _("Permissions"),
            {
                "fields": (
                    "is_active",
                    "is_staff",
                    "is_superuser",
                    "groups",
                    "user_permissions",
                ),
            },
        ),
        (_("Important dates"), {"fields": ("last_login", "date_joined")}),
    )
```

Source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.0.x/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L47-L63

Now, for example, to add a custom `role` field:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import User


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = BaseUserAdmin.fieldsets
    fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] = fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] + (
        'role',
    )


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another similar solution ([Took from here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180625181014/https://dyve.net/post/django-custom-user-model-admin/)):

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .models import User


class UserAdminWithExtraFields(UserAdmin):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserAdminWithExtraFields, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        abstract_fields = [field.name for field in AbstractUser._meta.fields]
        user_fields = [field.name for field in self.model._meta.fields]

        self.fieldsets += (
            (_('Extra fields'), {
                'fields': [
                    f for f in user_fields if (
                        f not in abstract_fields and
                        f != self.model._meta.pk.name
                    )
                ],
            }),
        )


admin.site.register(User, UserAdminWithExtraFields)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more simple similar situation

```py
# models.py
class User(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_("Age"), default=0, blank=True)
```

```py
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .models import User


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'age')
```

```py
# settings.py
...
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myapp.User"
...
```