# Django: Creating a superuser with a custom User model

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, root

I replaced the built-in auth user model with a custom model that requires email to sign in. What happens now though, is that I can't create a superuser.

Here are my models:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
        def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None, 
                                                       ):
                '''
                Create a CustomUser with email, name, password and other extra fields
                '''
                now = timezone.now()
                if not email:
                        raise ValueError('The email is required to create this user')
                email = CustomUserManager.normalize_email(email)
                cuser = self.model(email=email, first_name=first_name,
                                                        last_name=last_name, is_staff=False, 
                            is_active=True, is_superuser=False,
                                                        date_joined=now, last_login=now,)
                cuser.set_password(password)
                cuser.save(using=self._db)
                return cuser

        def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None, 
                                                           ):
                u = self.create_user(email, first_name, last_name, password, 
                                                           )
                u.is_staff = True
                u.is_active = True
                u.is_superuser = True
                u.save(using=self._db)

                return u

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
        '''
        Class implementing a custom user model. Includes basic django admin
        permissions and can be used as a skeleton for other models. 

        Email is the unique identifier. Email, password and name are required
        '''
        email = models.EmailField(_('email'), max_length=254, unique=True,
                                                                validators=[validators.validate_email])
        username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, blank=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=45)
        last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=45)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
                                help_text=_('Determines if user can access the admin site'))
        is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

        objects = CustomUserManager()

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

        def get_full_name(self):
                '''
                Returns the user's full name. This is the first name + last name
                '''
                full_name = "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
                return full_name.strip()

        def get_short_name(self):
                '''
                Returns a short name for the user. This will just be the first name
                '''
                return self.first_name.strip()
```

I use this to create the superuser:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser --email=example@gmail.com
```

and then I get my prompts(First name, Last name, Password) and this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 141, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/Users/yudasinal1/Documents/Django/git/Django_project_for_EGG/logins/models.py", line 50, in create_superuser
    date_joined=timezone.now(), last_login=timezone.now(),)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 417, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'is_superuser' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Not sure, why.

Also, how can I make the system prompt to create a superuser, when creating a database (like the built in user does)?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to add `PermissionsMixin` to `CustomUser` base classes:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
```

Comment: worked! thank you!
quick question: for my user form to appear in admin do I have to write it separately? cause now I only have Groups in my Auth section in admin

Comment: @yudasinal check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012235/using-django-auth-useradmin-for-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Wow. Well spotted. Thanks!