# Django: Making the CustomUser appear in admin under Auth

Tags: django, forms, customization, admin

How to make my CustomUser appear in admin under auth app like built-in user? I know there was a question like that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012235/using-django-auth-useradmin-for-a-custom-user-model) and I followed the solution people suggested, but what their solution do, is that it makes a Customer User in my app, not in an auth app, so like any other model that I create.

Here are my models:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
        def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None, 
                                                      **extra_fields):
                '''
                Create a CustomUser with email, name, password and other extra fields
                '''
                now = timezone.now()
                if not email:
                        raise ValueError('The email is required to create this user')
                email = CustomUserManager.normalize_email(email)
                cuser = self.model(email=email, first_name=first_name,
                                                        last_name=last_name, is_staff=False, 
                            is_active=True, is_superuser=False,
                                                        date_joined=now, last_login=now,)
                cuser.set_password(password)
                cuser.save(using=self._db)
                return cuser

        def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None, 
                                                  **extra_fields):
                u = self.create_user(email, first_name, last_name, password, 
                                                  **extra_fields)
                u.is_staff = True
                u.is_active = True
                u.is_superuser = True
                u.save(using=self._db)

                return u

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        '''
        Class implementing a custom user model. Includes basic django admin
        permissions and can be used as a skeleton for other models. 

        Email is the unique identifier. Email, password and name are required
        '''
        email = models.EmailField(_('email'), max_length=254, unique=True,
                                                                validators=[validators.validate_email])
        username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, blank=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=45)
        last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=45)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
                                help_text=_('Determines if user can access the admin site'))
        is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

        objects = CustomUserManager()

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

        def get_full_name(self):
                '''
                Returns the user's full name. This is the first name + last name
                '''
                full_name = "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
                return full_name.strip()

        def get_short_name(self):
                '''
                Returns a short name for the user. This will just be the first name
                '''
                return self.first_name.strip()
```

And I also want to add `ManyToManyField` to 2 other models I have and make them appear in the user form in admin.

Does it mean that I have to write my own form? Or maybe I can just copy the source code for the built-in user form and change it to my names?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need it in the auth app? Why does that matter? If you really need to do that, you can just add an `app_label` variable in the `Meta

```
class Meta:
    app_label = 'auth'
```

This will change the table names, so you will need to migrate those.

for the `ManyToManyField`, I would just override the appropriate auth forms and add those fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
But how do I make the form for the User to be the same as the built in but with specific for me fields? Does it mean I should just copy the forms from the source code and change some names and add fields?

Comment: No, just inherit from the built in form, (like `CustomForm(UserAddForm):` then override what you need.