# DjangoAdmin - how to include customUser into auth App?

Tags: django, admin

I created a custom user following the django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) and is working fine (django 1.6), but when I go to the admin site my new user model is registered under a different app it means auth has [Groups, Permission] and myApp has [MyUser], following the appname where my new MyUser class was created, but no inside "auth" like the standard user model. I just read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443049/django-making-the-customuser-appear-in-admin-under-auth) but what they suggested didn't work.

Any Idea? I tried to create a Proxy class and using the app_label tag over that one, but it didn't work ...if I use "auth" in that setting my new class don't show up in the admin, but if I use any other name, it does, but is not what I need (to have all together)

my project structure is as follows:

1. MyProject

   - myApp

     - models.py (my new user lives here)
     - admin.py
   - MyProject

     - settings.py --> AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myApp.CustomUser'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need it to show up under 'auth' ?

Comment: to keep consistency ...just let's call it business requirements lol

Comment: Which version of Django are you using, please?

Comment: oh sorry about that...it's 1.6!