# How do I put custom user models into Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-settings

So, I have a model with 3 custom user classes:

```
class customUser(AbstractBaseUser):

class customUser(AbstractBaseUser):

class customUser(AbstractBaseUser):
```

I need all of them to be in Django's admin like Users and Groups in Django by default.
AUTH_USER_MODEL doesn't support tuples. Or what should I do?
May someone help?

Comment: Why inherit from `BaseUserManager`. If you want to create custom user models you have to `AbstractBaseUser`. In any case, `AUTH_USER_MODEL` does not support tuples. Maybe some insight in your use-case would give us more options on how to help you.

Comment: Why dont you just add it to the admin, like other models?

Comment: This has been asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012235/using-django-auth-useradmin-for-a-custom-user-model