# How do I add an extra field in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django

I'm just starting out with Django and I've just revamped my project so that instead of using the base user, I use an AbstractUser model, as defined in my models.py folder

```
#accounts/models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # add additional fields in here
    favourite_colour = models.CharField("Favourite Colour", max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I've also created the creation forms that work well with my signup system

```
#accounts/forms.py

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'favourite_colour')

        help_texts = {
                    'username': 'Make something unique',
                    'email': None,
                    }

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'favourite_colour')
```

And now I am trying to edit the admin page so that I can change a users `favourite_colour` attribute. So far I have this in my `admin.py` file

```
#accounts/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['username', 'email', 'favourite_colour']

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Which shows me the `favourite_colour` of each user
[image]

My question is, **how do I make a field to edit this `CustomUser` attribute once you've clicked on a user?**, for example like this [image] I'd welcome any help at all as I'm not too good at reading the docs. Please ask if you need more code adding to the question, I've never asked a Django question before

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some more looking I found a `fieldsets` option ([link1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model), [link2](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1314/), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012235/using-django-auth-useradmin-for-a-custom-user-model)) that can be used inside of my `CustomUserAdmin` code. In my `CustomUserAdmin` class I now have:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['username', 'email', 'favourite_colour']

    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
            ('Extra Fields', {'fields': ('favourite_colour',)}),
    )
```