# Django: Reference user's first_name using AbstractUser?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-users

My goal is to add non-authentication values to a user. Like, bio, nationality, etc. I am trying to use a custom user model. I am having trouble accessing the values. I can use the new ones I created, but not the original ones like first_name, last_name, email.

my model.py looks like

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)    
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

Settings.py I added:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'publication.User'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'publication.apps.PublicationConfig,
    ...
```

My admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

How to I add bio and nickname to the admin page?

And how do I access first name, email, bio, phone outside in forms and such?

Many thanks.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012235/using-django-auth-useradmin-for-a-custom-user-model, I think that with the most upvoted answers you should be fine. You need to extend `UserAdmin` with your fields.

Comment: did you run the migrations?

Comment: I did run the migrations! Early on to make sure that the user model was done properly. Migrating is major headache according to the docs. I am having a little trouble figuring this one out @gdef_ :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Django's `UserAdmin`, that is adding all the things you see in the admin forms for your user. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L41).

If you want to add your fields you need to create a custom model admin class from scratch or extend the one you want. You can extend and override things in the `UserAdmin` that you are using. Check the structure of `add_fieldsets` and `fieldsets`, adding fields to those tuples will add them to the admin.

For example to add `bio` and `phone` to the form:

```
@admin.register(models.User)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('bio', 'phone')}),
    ) + UserAdmin.fieldsets
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('bio', 'phone')}),
    ) + UserAdmin.fieldsets
```

Read more about how to customize the admin [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets).

Comment: I was able to get the fields in the admin site but whenever I try and add a user I get an error.
`First, enter a username and password. Then, you’ll be able to edit more user options.

Please correct the errors below.`

But there are no errors in the fields. I tried empty, filled. Only username and pass. But nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @gdef_'s answer,

The best way to add information to a user I found was to do a custom user model using `Abstractuser`. This simplified things a lot. This has to be done early in the project before the first migration, actually, I would recommend this to be done every time. I will use this from now on.

Things worth noting, when registering models in admin.py. The abstract models should be registered this way:

```
admin.site.register(CustomUser,CustomUserAdmin)
```

but for other models use a decorator:

```
@admin.register(Story)
class StoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','title','get_date_formatted', 'author')
    ... 
    more stuff
```